# Android developers syncadapter tutorial out of date?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-syncadapter

Is the android developers syncadapter tutorial out of date.

Because i was trying to implement a sync adapter in my application that syncs data to a server. But when implementing the following part i get eclipse errors.

Implementing the syncadapter that syncs when network is available:

Android developers tutorial:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    // Constants
    // Content provider authority
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.datasync.provider";
    // Account
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "default_account";
    // Global variables
    // A content resolver for accessing the provider
    ContentResolver mResolver;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        // Get the content resolver for your app
        mResolver = getContentResolver();
        // Turn on automatic syncing for the default account and authority
        mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, true);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What happens in my code:
Have the following variables

```
// Constants
// The authority for the sync adapter's content provider
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.datasync.provider";
// An account type, in the form of a domain name
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "example.com";
// The account name
public static final String ACCOUNT = "dummyaccount";
// Instance fields
Account mAccount;
// Global variables
// A content resolver for accessing the provider
ContentResolver mResolver;
```

and in oncreate i do this:

```
mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);
// Get the content resolver for your app
mResolver = getContentResolver();
// Turn on automatic syncing for the default account and authority
mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, true);
```

I get an error in eclipse in the **mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, true);** it says the following:

**The method setSyncAutomatically(Account, String, boolean) in the type ContentResolver is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, boolean)**

So i am stuck here the tutorial tells me to do this but the ACCOUNT needs to be the type Account and not string. Is the tutorial out of date?

Comment: Log a request with Google so they can update the tutorial if you believe it's out of date. It's the best way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

Account newAccount = new Account("AccountName","com.example.accountType"); This can be used to access the account you already created.

Comment: I know i can use the mAccount variable for that not to give me an error. my question is is the tutorial out of date?

Comment: It is not out of date it is wrong. As far as I know there was never a string parameter

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `setSyncAutomatically` is an [`Account`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html) object, not a String. You are using a String. You need to use [`AccountManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to obtain the proper Account and use that.

Comment: i know, that's not my question, my question is why is this wrong in the tutorials? it should use the mAccount right? but they don't do it there.

Answer (score 0):

The account parameter is from type Account. I have the full Android documentation on each of my devices and the BasicSyncAdapter (http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/BasicSyncAdapter.zip) of google is compilable via AIDE, but at the points of a custom Authenticator and the SyncAdapter not everything is described as clear as possible. I hope this example could help you a bit: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/